# Массивы и коллекции являются reified (овеществленные) или non-reified типами?

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции

Массивы и коллекции являются reified (овеществленные) или non-reified типами?

Comment: По возможности подскажите, где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Лучше скажи, где ты сам такое прочитал. Вроде бы в джаве нет таких понятий.

Comment: стр. 169, Java: эффективное программирование, 3-е изд.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вроде там понятно написано:

> Вторым важным отличием массивов от обобщенных типов является то, что
> массивы являются типами, доступными при выполнении (reified) [25, 4.7]. Это
> значит, что массивы знают тип элементов во время выполнения и обеспечивают его. Как было сказано ранее, попытавшись сохранить String в массив
> Long, вы получите исключение `ArrayStoreException`. Обобщенные типы,
> напротив, реализуются с использованием затирания (erasure) [25,4.6]. Это значит, что они обеспечивают ограничения на типы только на этапе компиляции,
> а затем отбрасывают (или затирают) информацию о типах элементов при выполнении. Затирание позволяет обобщенным типам свободно взаимодействовать со старым кодом, который не использует обобщенные типы (раздел 5.1),
> обеспечивая плавный переход к обобщенным типам в Java 5.

---

Во всех generic'ах типы удаляются при компиляции, но массив - это не generic.

Соответственно массивы - reified, всё остальное - нет.

Впрочем, никогда не встречал эту терминологию по отношению к дажаве.

https://ideone.com/06F923
https://ideone.com/ETa1Nb